# Repaint большого объёма данных

Tags: java, swing

Делаю анимацию поиска выхода из лабиринта.

В методе `paintComponent()` прорисовываю всю матрицу. Ну и для анимации вызываю `repaint()`. Если сетка `50х50`, то перерисовка идёт относительно быстро, наблюдать приятно. Но загрузил лабиринт `1000х1000` и понимаю, что даже без задержки анимация будет крутиться недели 2...

Какой кто знает выход? Прорисовывать например только то, что реально изменилось, а не все ячейки.

Comment: Решение, например - прорисовывать только каждый сотый шаг. А сколько по времени считается алгоритм для матрицы 1000х1000 без прорисовки?

Comment: Полный обход BFS или DFS очень быстро, секунду-две. А рисовать хотелось бы всё-таки на каждом шаге...

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, секунда для алгоритма - это не быстро, секунда - это целое процессорное ядро занятое в течении секунды, миллиарды циклов. А теперь представь, что каждый шаг твоего алгоритма, который занимает одну миллионную секунду должен быть утяженён перерисовкой всего поля, что является тяжёлой ui-операцией. Другой эксперимент - посчитай общее количество шагов, которое нужно алгоритму, подели его на 30 (30 кадров в секунду - максимум того, что может уловить человеческих глаз). Так что, если ты действительно хочешь показать пользователю каждый шаг, то ты получишь время, которое на это понадобиться, и оно будет огромно. Так что не боясь  пропускай шаги, и рисуй каждый сотый/тысячный шаг, можно делать специфическую подсветку, чтобы, например, пользователь видел сразу все клетки пересчитанные за пропущенные шаги, например - подсвеченные другим цветом.

Ну а если ты действительно хочешь просто оптимизировать - можно вместо перерисовки всего поля перерисовывать только обновившуюся ячейку.

Comment: можно вместо перерисовки всего поля перерисовывать только обновившуюся ячейку --- как???

Comment: Если в paintComponent() не вызывать super(), то старое состояние не будет очищено - можно рисовать поверх старого нужные куски (эти куски нужно где-то запоминать при просчёте). Плюс - если перерисовывается только конкретный квадратный кусок - можно вызвать репеинт только этой области https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint-int-int-int-int-, но это не даст особого прироста, если не комбинировать с предыдущим подходом

Comment: О, это может сработать. Предполагаю только, что если во время анимации двигать/ресайзить окно, то старое содержимое не от рисуется. Я прав?

Comment: При ресайде - лучше перерисовывать весь канвас

Comment: Вы оценили количество шагов при обсчёте лабиринта 1000х1000?